# Aggregate multiple values in one field in Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I need to aggregate multiple values in one field with a query, I'll try to explain it better with an example:
let suppose i have a "Purchase Orders" table as follow:

```
POID - InvoiceID - POValue
1    - 1         - 100
2    - 2         - 200
3    - 3         - 700
```

and a second table "Account Managers" as follow:

```
POID - InvoiceID - AccountManager
1    - 1         - Luke
1    - 1         - Mike
2    - 2         - Mike
3    - 3         - Ralph
3    - 3         - Luke
```

and what I want to achieve is:

```
POID - InvoiceID - AccountManagers - POValue
1    - 1         - Luke, Mike      - 100
2    - 2         - Mike            - 200
3    - 3         - Ralph, Luke     - 700
```

In SQL I'd do it with "STUFF" but i'm not able to find an equivalent for Access.

Any ideas on how I can do it?

Thanks in advance,

Kryer

Comment: This function might help: http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html